# Python remove specific elements from list on repeated steps

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, loops

I have a list of n elements (divisible to 56). From each 'step' of 56 elements, I would like to remove specific elements on same indices in each step:. Let's say I have a list of 280 elements and I want to separate it by 56 elements, that will be 5 lists. And from each list to remove specific indices (index variable down below for example).

```
index = [1, 8, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49]

my_list = ['4','5', '3', '7'.... '1'] #at least 56 elements
len(my_list) # Out: 280, for example
new_l = []


for i in my_list[0:56]:
     if i not in index:
        new_l.append(i)
```

I would like to iterate repeatedly trough my_list a step with 56 elements and remove those specific indices from index variable. Thanks in advance and may the force be with you!

Comment: By **step**, I think you mean **slice**. Both can not be used interchangeably.

Comment: Give a real, simplified example.  Maybe a list of 20 elements and step of 7 or some such.  Give sample input and output as the result you want is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to both chunk and filter a list at the same time.

```
indices = [1, 3, 5]
s = 6
t = list(range(30))

[[v for j, v in enumerate(t[i:i+s]) if j not in indices] for i in range(0, len(t), s)]
# [[0, 2, 4], [6, 8, 10], [12, 14, 16], [18, 20, 22], [24, 26, 28]]
```

Comment: That's it mate. Thanks for catching my thoughts, even that I couldn't explain them well :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a *list comprehension* generating indices and items concurrently with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Taking the *modulo* of the index on 56 gives you a number between 0 and 55 which can be used for the filtering based on the values in the `index` list:

```
new_l = [x for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if i%56 not in index]
```

Bear in mind that indexing starts from 0. In case your `index` list does not take this into account, you can pass a `start` of 1 to `enumerate`.

<sub>*Pro-Tip*: Making `index` list a set will reduce the membership look-up complexity to *O*(1).</sub>

Comment: Thanks mate, but that's not the case. Let's say I have 224 elements in my_list. I would like to iterate from [0:56] and on each iteration to remove elements corresponding to index list.

Comment: You only want to check the slice `[0:56]` once or repeatedly?

Comment: Yes, repeatedly :)

Comment: @HristoStoychev Well, that's what the answer does. You don't need to take slices, just fold the current index using `mod 56` :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understood your question. The way I get it, you want to remove every 56th element in `my_list` from the `index` list. If this is correct, you should use the slice `[0::56]`, not `[0:56]`. The latter will give you the first 56 elements.

Here's a simplified example, removing every 2nd element, with both lists being identical so it's easier to keep track of what's happening:

```
>>> index = [1, 8, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49]
>>> my_list = [1, 8, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49]
>>> to_remove = set(my_list[0::2])  # {1, 14, 28, 42}
>>> [x for x in index if x not in to_remove]
[8, 21, 35, 49]
```

In your case, you would use `to_remove = set(my_list[0::56])`. Here, `0` is the starting index (default is `0`), and `56` the interval between elements (default is `1`).

If, instead, you want to keep those of the 56th elements that are not in `index` (as your code suggests), you can use this:

```
>>> index_set = set(index)
>>> [x for x in my_list[0::56] if x not in index_set]
```

---

Okay, I think *now* I got what you want:

```
>>> index = [1, 3]
>>> my_list = list(range(20))
>>> [x for n in range(0, len(my_list), 5) 
       for i, x in enumerate(my_list[n:n+5]) if i not in index]
[0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 17, 19]
```